# How to set the view on top in ios SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I had tried this code, I have also tried with stacks but not able to align with top .
I just want the view to appear on top with auto layout as like UIKit .

```
import SwiftUI

struct ItemDetail: View {
    let item : MenuItem
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top){
            VStack{
                Image(item.mainImage)
                Text(item.description)
            }
            .padding(10)
            .background(.red)
            .navigationTitle(item.name)
        }
        
    }
}

struct ItemDetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ItemDetail(item: MenuItem.example)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the `HStack` for a `VStack` and add a `Spacer()` at the end. e.g.:

```
struct ItemDetail: View {
    let item : MenuItem
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack{
                Image(item.mainImage)
                Text(item.description)
            }
            .padding(10)
            .background(.red)
            .navigationTitle(item.name)

            Spacer()
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
    VStack()
    {
        VStack
        {
            Image(item.mainImage)
            Text(item.description)
        }
        .padding(10)
        .background(.red)
        .navigationTitle(item.name)

        Spacer()
    }
```

Comment: This works in the simulator but not in preview mode.?

Comment: @KushagraChandra I don't see why this would be different in preview.